# Trouble using AspNetUsers table within Clean Architecture in Asp.net core web api 6.0

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-identity, clean-architecture

We are migrating our ASP.NET Core 3.1 project to ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API (clean architecture).
https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture

In our old project, we use IdentityUser (which is not in clean architecture) like this:

old project - User.cs

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    // removed
}  
// This is the table named as AspNetUser in the database
```

Now, in our clean architecture project,

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{}
```

is inside the Infrastructure layer.

The database connection is in the domain layer (which is not dependent on any other layers).

In the domain layer, I have a `User.cs` class. This is same as User.cs in our old project. But I could not extends `IdentityUser` into my new `User` class. Because in clean architecture, we maintain Identity related files in Infrastructure Layer.

New project - User.cs

```
public  class User 
{
   // removed
}
```

My issue is I want to use a foreign key from the `AspnetUser` table to another class.

Example: `FK_SiteUsers_AspNetUsers_UserId`.

But `ApplicationUser` (which extends `IdentityUser`) is in the Infrastructure layer. Could not use this class into domain Layer in clean architecture

How can I do this?
Please anyone help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Surely all of your table classes & context (extending `IdentityDbContext`?) would be defined in the Domain layer? Though you could extend that in your application / infrastructure layers. Bringing everything together in your Startup class.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman The `IdentityDbContext` shouldn't be in the Domain layer because the Domain shouldn't know about the technologies used (e.g. ASP .Net Core Identity). @hanushi See this example, there is no hard link (e.g. a foreign key) for the identity user, but you would put a column in your Domain `User` that points to `ApplicationUser` https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnWeb/blob/main/src/ApplicationCore/Entities/BuyerAggregate/Buyer.cs#L9

Comment: @MattU Could you please explain more about this example. I did not get your point

Comment: The point is that you can't have the foreign key that you want, if you're using this pattern, but you can still add a column to a table that contains the Id of the Identity user.

Comment: So, When creating new user I have to save userId into 2 tables? AspNetUsers and another-user-table